# How to apply a script to a certain file/folder through a right click in explorer (for UNC-paths)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer, batch, context-menu

I'm looking for a way to apply a cmd or powershell script to a certain file by right clicking the file in windows explorer and choosing "Apply script XYZ".

A use case would be to make a file write protected, so my batch file would contain:

```
attrib +r %filename%
```

where `%filename%` is the name of the file I right clicked on in explorer.

Single file would do the trick for now, but I would be interested in applying it to multiple files (by selecting multiple files in a folder) and whole folders (by selecting the folder) as well.

The solution should work for Windows 10 and, if possible, for UNC-paths and Windows 7 as well.

**EDIT**:
So far I managed to get everything done expect for the UNC-Paths, this example works for files (using [this source](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu) and [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)):

**Registry Entry:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SomeName]
@="NameOfTheMenueItem"
"icon"="someicon.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SomeName\command]
@="\"X:\\folder\\batchfile.cmd\" \"%1\""
```

**Batch File:**

```
set filepath=%1
attrib +r %filepath%
```

**Batch File (for folders):**

```
set folderpath=%1
attrib +r %folderpath%\*.*
```

Remaining Problems:

- I need it to work for UNC-Paths
- return the folderpath to the batchfile without "" in order to change it to `"X:\folderpath\*.*"` (at the moment I get `"X:\folderpath"` as a return value, although just adding `\*.*` works the result `"X:\folderpath"\*.*` does not look very good, not sure if there will be any problems at some point)
- create a recursive write protect for all files and sub-folders for a chosen folder

Comment: just found some basic instruction [here](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu). So I should be able to do it for a single file. Still looking for a solution for UNC-paths, for multiple files and for whole folders and the icon problem.

Comment: This answer does both files and folders ... https://superuser.com/a/1070883/337631

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I linked to that question myself in my first comment and explained why it's not a duplicate, David linked to it as well.

Comment: FYI: You don't write-protect a folder by setting its read-only attribute.

Comment: @KeithMiller thanks, that was s.th. left over from a previous version of the question. I edited the question.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't provide a UNC path to your script or that items navigated to via UNC don't have the context menu item?

Comment: @KeithMiller honstly I did not check it myself yet. my [source](https://superuser.com/a/1070883/201818) says it will not work for UNC paths